# Use theme template with specific Views

Tags: 8, views, theming

I have a D8 subtheme of Bootstrap and on the homepage I have 2 Views (2 carousel views).

I turned on twig debugging so I could see which template file(s) is (are) being used, and where it starts and ends.  When I used this before it included a listing of sample alternate filenames for that specific content (e.g. *paragraph--about-us-page--full.html.twig*), which was a big help.

For each of the views on the homepage, they are shown using **views-view.html.twig** and **views-view-field.html.twig** whether from the module template, bootstrap template or my copy of the files into my theme.

Is there a way to set up a template file for each of the views individually?

View Machine Names:

- homepage_slider
- homepage_loans

They only reside on the front page.  I have tried renaming files to see if I can see it being used in the Twig debugging and frequently clear the cache.

It could be a Page, View, Block, etc. template, but then how do I reference the parts of the View to control the display of the fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is in this section: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions#s-views

Specifically,

> views-view-field.html.twig based patterns are postfixed with the
> view's field id (as in replacement patterns) to display a single field
> in a view:
>
> - views-view-field--[viewid]--[view-display-id]--[fieldid].html.twig
> - views-view-field--[viewid]--page--[fieldid].html.twig
> - views-view-field--block--[fieldid].html.twig
> - views-view-field--[fieldid].html.twig
> - views-view-field.html.twig

Comment: This helped.  The difficulty was finding the order to put everything and whether to separate with 2 "--" or 1 "-".  It's still a work in progress but this let me take steps forward.  I've also copied over all of the files being referenced in the debug output so I know which to modify and any that I don't touch I am going to delete and let bootstrap/module/core handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see these suggestions is due the the following bug, [#2923634: Use hook_theme_suggestions in views](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923634)

Comment: Thanks.  This explains it now showing up so I worked around it.